# performance difference - distinct() vs dropDuplicates()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

At high level both helps achieve same of removing duplicates. Is there any performance difference between distinct vs dropDuplicates()?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35666967/spark-sql-dataframe-distinct-vs-dropduplicates?rq=2

Comment: @HimadriPal thanks for sharing. I went through the mentioned post earlier and understand the functionality. I'm trying to follow the performance aspects between two operations.

Comment: no difference. under the hood, they're basically the same function.